# Non-static method error in PHP PEAR Email

Tags: php, smtp, pear

Am trying to sending out emails from a PHP application using PEAR. Email is sending out successfully, but i got the below errors. This is the code am using for

```
include('Mail.php');
include('Mail/mime.php');
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "test@gmail.com";
$password = "123456";
$to = 'test1@gmail.com';
$from = "TEST <test@gmail.com>";
$replyto = "TEST <test@gmail.com>";
$subject = "TEST";
$name = TEST;

$headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$html = "<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Dear " . $name . ",</p>
        <p>Test email</p>
    </body>

</html>";
$mime_params = array(
    'text_encoding' => '7bit',
    'text_charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'html_charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'head_charset' => 'UTF-8'
);

$crlf = "\n";
$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
//$body = $mime->get(array('text_charset' => 'utf-8'));
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
//$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');
$body = $mime->get($mime_params);
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
$mail = $smtp->send($bcc, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("" . $mail->getMessage() . "");
}
```

Error messages

```
Strict Standards: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 154

Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in /var/www/qcmc/registration2016/completed.php on line 252

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 225

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 339

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 344

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 347

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 390

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 394

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 236

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 494

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 637

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 641

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 649

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 653

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 657

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 662

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 528

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 156

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 249

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 269

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 779

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 782

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 221

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 224

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 276

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 282

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 809

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 812

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 291

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 871

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 874

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 878

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 881

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 364

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 367

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 370

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 225

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 339

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 344

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 347

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 390

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 394

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 236

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 494

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 637

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 641

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 649

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 653

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 657

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 662

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 528

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 156

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 249

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 269

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 779

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 782

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 221

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 224

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 276

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 282

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 809

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 812

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 303

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::getStaticProperty() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 871

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 1015

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 1018

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 286

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::getStaticProperty() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 871

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically in /var/www/qcmc/registration2016/completed.php on line 287

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281
Failed to add recipient: @localhost [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 555, response: 5.5.2 Syntax error. c20sm50575655pfj.47 - gsmtp)]
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/share/php/Mail.php:154) in /var/www/qcmc/registration2016/completed.php on line 294

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 364

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 196

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 367

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 370

Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 281
```

Answer (score 1):

- Those are warnings, not errors
- This is fixed in PEAR 1.10.1